# performace:select from another db2.table using connection to db1 in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

I wanted to know if there is any performace issues if i use same connection to do select,update etc.. in to another database. 
My app uses 2 databases one for transaction data and one for master data. so i want to maintain only one connection and do all queries to db2 as select * from db2.table or update db2.table. Could anybody suggest if it has any performace difference compared to connecting to db2 and doing querying?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's any performance implications. Selecting a database just makes it the default, so you don't have to send the database prefix.

Comment: thanks Barmar. hope it doesnt affect transactions etc.. too

Comment: Transactions are dependent on the engine of the database in the query, not the default database.